# Freshclam error

Tags: clamav

After installing clamav and clamtk, when doing freshclam I receive this message:

```
freshclam
ERROR: Can't create temporary directory /var/lib/clamav/clamav-f52645d8e80b9b727228734e339d231d
Hint: The database directory must be writable for UID 1000 or GID 1000
```

Could somebody help?

Comment: So I re-installed it, used sudo freshclam and what i got was this: http://pastebin.com/kh9Q1h3K Is there anyway that warning is fixed? I'm asking because I can't seem to install it from the tar.gz file of the home page. I will leave this as solved and wait for the repositories, thank you all. [SOLVED]

Comment: This is not a forum, we do not use "[SOLVED]" here. The format of this site is Question -> Answer, so If you have an answer please feel free to add an answer to your own question, or if an answer solved your question click on the green check next to the answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember getting this issue when I first started using clamav, going back through my notes I found I had written this:

First find out my uid and gid by typing at the command prompt: `id your_username`

Should give you a long line of text with a uid and gid in it somewhere, then type:
`sudo chown UID.GID /var/lib/clamav`
then
`sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/clamav`

Change UID and GID with the values you got from the id Command above.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, run `freshclam` with `sudo`:

`sudo freshclam`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/19931-ubuntu-1204-clamav-problem-with-updating

In Terminal:

**Stop the updater:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop
```

**Update:**

```
sudo freshclam -v
```

**Start the updater:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in a docker container and could resolve it by adding:

```
AllowSupplementaryGroups true
```

to /etc/clamav/clamd.conf

Hope that helps.